# Getting error in manage categories - not found for attribute "navigation_column"

Tags: magento

After trying to install one extension and trying to uninstall, deleting all their files (extension) - we are now getting errors when trying to go in `admin > manage categories`:

```
Source model "gomage_navigation/adminhtml_system_config_source_category_column" not found for attribute "navigation_column"

Trace:
#0 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "g...')
#1 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(430): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(430): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#11 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(430): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(263): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#21 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(191): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#22 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#23 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /home/vinylshop/domains/vinylshop.lt/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess it could have created a new attribute for the categories that it is now trying to find, but it cannot.

Look through your eav_attribute tables and see if there is anything in there. Better yet, go through the extensions install scripts to see if it added any attributes.

Comment: Where I can found eav_attribute tables?