# Source model "maattabel/categorie" not found for attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

**After installing & then uninstalling magento extension, i am getting error opening 
Catalog > Manage Categories. Please help out. I tried to follow this solution but i am not sure what to do after i got table : [Getting error in manage categories - not found for attribute "navigation_column"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400782/getting-error-in-manage-categories-not-found-for-attribute-navigation-column)**

---

### Extension : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sizing-chart.html

```
a:5:{i:0;s:80:"Source model "maattabel/categorie" not found for attribute "maattabel_categorie"";i:1;s:4465:"#0 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
#1 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#11 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#21 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#22 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#23 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /home/citysho6/public_html/mydomain.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:92:"/index.php/M8y0I8n7k1f3l4a5m6e7/catalog_category/index/key/7f99b1cb5fd739c82726e5f8a7a2f6c2/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: maybe the folder is called category and its spelt wrong in the code as categorie?

Comment: no this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create a module with a setup script. In the setup script put:

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'navigation_column');
$this->endSetup();
```

Clear cache and session folders in var folder then go to your site again. It will now run the setup script and remove the offending attribute.

Here is a module creator that will enable you to make a bare bones module with the setup script.

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Comment: Hello, I followed your steps but i am not able to create module with script you have given. where to put setup script ? sorry but i have never created magneto module before, please help me out. or give any article to learn from...